# How to find out which Jakarta EE implementations are used by WildFly?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

WildFly is a Jakarta EE compatible application server. This means that all of the Jakarta EE APIs have to be implemented by the server.
I am interested in the concrete implementations that WildFly is using for a specific version of WildFly. What is the best way to create a table with columns Jakarta EE API - Implementation of WildFly (or is there some online resource listing this)?
I have looked deeply into the WildFly documentation, but so far without success.

Comment: Look at the RedHat BOM file for the version of wildfly you are interested in.

Comment: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/jboss-javaee-8.0/1.0.4.Final/jboss-javaee-8.0-1.0.4.Final.pom

Comment: @K.Nicholas: Thanks for the input, that's already helpful. However, I tried to search for CXF or Resteasy (two implementations of which I know that WildFly is using them) and didn't find them in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look here. Maybe a little old, but they don't change the implementation often, so probably they will be using the same dependency, just updated

https://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2020/05/implementation-components-used-by.html

Answer (score 1):

The implementations are stored in the `modules` directory within the Wildfly installation directory.  Everything is under `modules/system/layers/base`.  So, for `wildfly-21.0.1.Final`, you have:

```
org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/main/resteasy-jaxrs-3.13.2.Final.jar
```

for example.  This gets complicated fast, however.  Take the servlet implementation.  Wildfly has two parts.  The first is the spec itself:

```
javax/servlet/api/main/jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar
```

and then the code that does the real work:

```
io/undertow/servlet/main/undertow-servlet-2.2.2.Final.jar
```

So you'd have to dig pretty deep to know the "real" implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The newest release is implementing Jakarta EE 8.

The versions of the included specifications can be found in the Jakarta EE 8 documentation https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/

Comment: Where can I find the implementations WildFly is using on this site?

Comment: Checkout the pom.xml https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can refer Jakarta EE compliance page any time here:

https://jakarta.ee/compatibility/#tab-one

There are full list of compatible implementations there.

So WildFly 18.0.0 is Jakarta EE 8 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The table can be found at the [WildFly Documentation page](https://docs.wildfly.org/).

Right now the versions are as follows.

| WildFly Release | Jakarta EE Version | Java EE Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29.0.0.Final | Jakarta EE 10 |  |
| 28.0.0.Final | Jakarta EE 10 |  |
| 27.0.0.Final | Jakarta EE 10 |  |
| 26.1.0.Final | Jakarta EE 8 (and EE 9.1 Preview) |  |
| 26.0.0.Final | Jakarta EE 8 (and EE 9.1 Preview) |  |
| 25.0.0.Final | Jakarta EE 8 (and EE 9.1 Preview) |  |
| 24.0.0.Final | Jakarta EE 8 (and EE 9.1 Preview) |  |
| 23.0.0.Final | Jakarta EE 8 (and EE 9 Preview) |  |
| 22.0.0.Final | Jakarta EE 8 (and EE 9 Preview) | Java EE 8 |
| 21.0.0.Final | Jakarta EE 8 | Java EE 8 |
| 20.0.0.Final | Jakarta EE 8 | Java EE 8 |
| 19.1.0.Final | Jakarta EE 8 | Java EE 8 |
| 19.0.0.Final | Jakarta EE 8 | Java EE 8 |
| 18.0.0.Final | Jakarta EE 8 | Java EE 8 |
| 17.0.1.Final | Jakarta EE 8 | Java EE 8 |
| 17.0.0.Final |  | Java EE 8 |
| 16.0.0.Final |  | Java EE 8 |
| 15.0.0.Final |  | Java EE 8 |
| 14.0.0.Final |  | Java EE 8 |
| 13.0.0.Final |  | Java EE 7 (and full EE8 Preview) |
| 12.0.0.Final |  | Java EE 7 (and partial EE8 Preview) |